# unable to get posts using query_posts or wp_query on orders page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing a issue that query post wp_query is not working to get any post type even product post type on woocommerce orders page.

I have created a woocommerce folder in my thme

themeFolder->woocommerce->my-account->orders.php

if your order list is empty then functons works but if you have one or more orders `query_posts()` function this not woking even `wp_query()` is not working

I am not able to debug  because there is no log in debug file.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with Storefront theme and added template in theme as per your questions. Also, Placed two order and check wp_query and this is working fine.

Please check below screenshot in which you can see what I have done and check it your code.

Order Page - https://ibb.co/NSX20Rb

orders.php - https://ibb.co/2sWXGCs